# Sum Based on if a Value is available in different Table

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am trying to produce a % variance between 2 costs.

Cost 1) "CTS Cost" - this is the theoretical cost, what i believe it should have cost.

Cost 2) "CHILT Cost" - this is the actual cost, how much i am being billed for.

The "CTS Cost" is a prediction model based on business operations. This prediction model runs when Orders/Sales are input.

The "CHILT Cost" is an invoice stating actual costs and comes in the weekly report which comes through on every Monday for the previous weeks deliveries.

I am trying to calculate sum of CTS - Sum of CHILT and visualize the variance between the two.

This is my current measure -

```
Total_Cost_All_CTS = IF([Total_Cost_All_CHILT] = 0, BLANK(),[Total_Cost_Picking_CTS] + [Total_Cost_RHD_CTS] + [Total_Cost_Storage_CTS])
```

I only want to sum the sales from CTS if the value in CHILT is available.

Reason being that CTS model will give us figures for a sale that has been ordered but not delivered. Once it is delivered, the CHILT data is recieved.

There could be a few weeks between receiving this data and the sales being run through the CTS model.

This causes a Skew in my Variance as it is including data for CTS costs when we have either not yet received the data or may have a missing week.

Both the CTS and CHILT are in different tables with a relationship to a master date table.

I am not trying to match the data by sales, only by date.

For example,

Week 10 2019, CTS Cost - £10, CHILT Cost - £8, **Inlcude in CTS total**

Week 11 2019, CTS Cost - £10, CHILT Cost - No Data Recieved, **Dont Inlcude In CTS Total**

Week 12 2019, CTS Cost - £30, CHILT Cost - £20, **Inlcude in CTS total**

Week 13 2019, CTS Cost - £50, CHILT Cost - Data Due Next week, **Dont Inlcude In CTS Total**

Total CTS Cost for 2019 = £40

Total CHILT cost for 2019 = £28

Variance of £12

Currently my formula would say the total CTS Cost = £100 which then gives me a variance of £88.

The measure i have above works on when using WeekCommencing, however i need to do a total variance for the year, but exclude the weeks in the CTS total where there is no data or we have no received it yet so i can get a true variance between costs.

Please let me know if anymore information is required.

Thanks

LT

**EDIT**

I require the output to be a measure that is the SUM of CTS Costs where there was also a cost for CHILT during that week.

So based off of the example, i require a measure to hold the equation that gives me this result **"Total CTS Cost for 2019 = £40"**

Answer (score 0):

Create a measure like:

```
Variance = CALCULATE(SUM(Cost[CTS Cost]) - SUM(Cost[CHILT Cost]),FILTER(Cost,not ISBLANK(Cost[CHILT Cost])))
```

Result:
[image]

When you only want the rows where Chilt Cost is not blank you can add a filter:

[image]

Result:
[image]

Comment: thanks! Is there a way to make the calculation exclude the CTS cost if the CHILT cost is blank? So in you table above, week 11 & week 13 would be excluded from being displayed?

Comment: Yes, you need to create an extra column with an if else statement.

Comment: Thanks, im new to DAX and dont understand how i would do that and get a different result from my previous attempt at this with the example code in the question? 
Is this something you could help with?

Ive tried to use SUMX to work on a row by row basis but still got the same result?

 Like so? 

`CTS_Test = IF(SUMX(Chilt_Comb_Date_RHD, Chilt_Comb_Date_RHD[TOTAL_CHVALUE]) <> 0, SUMX(CTS_AC_Comb_Date_RHD, CTS_AC_Comb_Date_RHD[RHD_Cost]), blank())`

Comment: Go to table and click tab Modeling ->new column. Write: CTS Cost2 = if (not isblank(Chilt_Comb_Date_RHD), CTS_AC_Comb_Date_RHD)

Comment: My table is not aggregated to 1 line per date within each table. Could have the same dates but different products on each day, with each product having there own line.  I tried your solution above and the result was a total of ALL cts costs, i am after a sum only when the calculation finds the same date in the CHILT table and the sum of all products, for that date, sold that day is > 0. If it finds the date but no value in CHILT table, then don't include that weeks CTS costs within the Total CTS Cost. Same method for if no date is even found. IS this possible?

Comment: I am getting the feeling you are overcomplicating things. with my if else, you get a column with correct dat. If you do not want to show lines which hove no data, you can filter them out with the filter option of the visual element..

Comment: I think so, would you be able to provide and example to help me understand?